# Existence of an exponential double integral (for the probabilists: Are the $L^p$-norms of Brownian local time integrable in the space variable?)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, multivariable-calculus

I have encountered the following integral and, with a lot of handwaving and some identities for Gaussian integrals (see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions) I think that it is finite. Is there a "simple" way to prove this? The integral is as follows:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{1+1/p} \left(\int_{1}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{- x^2y^2/(2t)} (y-1)^p \mathrm{d}y \right)^{1/p} \mathrm{d}x,$$

where $t>0$ and $p > 1$.

For the probabilists: Up to a constant (depending on $t$), the above integral is equal to
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \operatorname{E}[(L_t^x)^p]^{1/p} \mathrm{d}x,$$
where $L_t^x$ is the local time of Browian motion in $x$ and at time $t$. The separate $L^p$-norms, i.e. the integrals $\operatorname{E}[(L_t^x)^p]$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (L_t^x)^p \mathrm{d}x$ are both finite, but when combining the two as above things seem to become a bit more difficult, especially because of this pesky exponent $1/p$. Is the finiteness some "well-known" result? Can it be deduced by a simple probabilistic argument?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: For p=1 you ought to be able to do it explicitly. If it turns out to be infinite in that case, then Jensen should say the rest are infinite too.

Comment: @NateEldredge Exactly, and for $p=1$ it is finite, which can also be deduced by probabilistic arguments.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thanks for your comment, your reasoning is similar to mine. My problem lies in justifying that the inner integral is $O(e^{cx^2})$. Is there a simpler way than calculating it explicitly? Keep in mind that integration by parts gives factors of $1/x$ which are then compensated by the $x^{1+1/p}$ on the outside.

Comment: @herrsimon: We don't have to (and, in my opinion, should not) evaluate anything explicitly: estimate the integrand by $Cy^Ne^{-ax^2y^2}$, say, and observe that $\int y^N e^{-(a/2)x^2y^2}\, dy \le C$, with a $C$ that doesn't depend on $x$ for $x\ge 1$. (Details are largely arbitrary as long as you don't squander the crucial terms.)

Comment: On second thoughts, this is incomplete because I also have a potential problem near $x=0$.

Comment: Not a big problem, though, because the exponential starts working when $y\gtrsim x^{-1-\epsilon}$, so for small $x$, the integral (with the power) will be $\lesssim x^{-1-\epsilon-1/p}$, which is still very safe.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I think that there's a typo in your comment above, the $C$ should also have $e^{-x^2}$ inside because otherwise the outer integral explodes. Also, I don't see any problem near $x=0$ using the reasoning above. I would be very happy if you could put your calculations into an answer with more details. If you don't have the time and nobody provides a "simple"  answer in the next days, I'll estimate it the hard and ugly way and post my results here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try a slightly more coherent write-up of my comments:

Write $I(x) = \int_1^{\infty} e^{-ax^2y^2}(y-1)^p\, dy$.

(1) If $0< x\le 1$, then we simply estimate
$$
I(x) \le x^{-p-1} \int_1^{\infty} e^{-at^2}t^p\, dt \lesssim x^{-p-1}
$$
(substitution $t=xy$). So $\int_0^1 x^{1+1/p} I(x)^{1/p}\, dx <\infty$.

(2) If $x>1$, then
$$
I(x) \le \int_1^{\infty} e^{-ax^2y^2} y^p\, dy \lesssim e^{-(a/2)x^2} ,
$$
say, essentially because the power becomes irrelevant in the presence of the decaying exponential. (More explicitly, we can bound the integrand by $Ce^{-(a/2)x^2}e^{-cy}$, with $c>0$ and then do the integral.)

Comment: I still didn't trust it and in the end carried out your estimates in a more detailed way :-) Anyway, it works, thank you very much!